# Unable to create Angular project Eclipse + WebClipse Angular IDE

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I am new to Angular and after I've installed Eclipse Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1) and  the WebClipse Angular IDE.

When I try to create a new Angular Project using the Wizard the terminal shows a Error.

"Directory drivers\etc does not exists; exiting
 If directory name is garbage you need to update your msys package"

My npm --version is 3.10.10

My ng --version is
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.11.3
os: win32 x64

I have not found anything online about this error and I'm stucked in this situation.

**Edit 1.**
Can't add a third screenshot with the error because my current reputation is too low, odd thing.

**Edit 2.**
Using the *Angular Eclipse* plugin I have a similar issue. It gives me the error
    *The 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.cmd' is not a ng file.*

[The New Angular Project menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7fQ3.png)

[The packages to be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG4s4.png)

Comment: Have you done "You need to update your msys package"?
P.S. Do you really need to use Eclipse? Why not the WebStorm for instance?

Comment: @slesh sincerly I have no idea of what does "update msys package" means, I've also tried to "apt-get install msys" because on a first instance I've thinked I missed some package from the Windows 10 Bash and it says msys doesn't exists.
About Eclipse, I use it as a java developer and I know the IDE, this is the only reason why I'm using it (It's a "developement for fun", not for work).

Comment: Do you get the same error when using the open source plug-in [_Angular Eclipse_](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse) instead of the commercial _WebClipse Angular IDE_?

Comment: @howlger I have uninstalled the WebClipse Angular IDE and installed the Angular Eclipse plugin, when I try to simply write the project name I recieve this error:
"The 'C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.cmd' is not a ng file."

Comment: @Andrea_DellOrto See https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/issues?q="is%20not%20a%20ng%20file"

Comment: @howlger I've read the link you shared, in my case I have not a project to import, so the project specific settings are created when I try to create a "new Project".
So, I've selected the "Use installed" for the Node.js setted as "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" and the "Install" option for the "Angular CLI" setting; I've selected the 1.4.3
Then I (finally) create the project and the Angular CLI installation starts.
Ok, now, the CLI seems to be installed, and the project folder is empty, nothing inside.
It's normal?
As I said, I am totally new to angular, I am a bit disorientated now.

Comment: Ok, got it (maybe), I've finally understand.
I've moved, using the terminal, inside the project directory, then used the command `ng new myproject` and after the installation, now I have the project folders.